# Question about the tactic "obtain"

Tags: tactic, lean-mathlib

I am having difficulty activating the tactic `obtain`. Is it part of mathlib and where is its exact location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Lean 3, the best way to answer these sort of questions is via the [mathlib tactic documentation](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html) (which also documents the built in tactics in core Lean).

If you look at [obtain](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#obtain) and select "Import using" you will see that either of these import commands work:

- `import tactic.rcases` (the specific location of the tactic)
- `import tactic.basic` (a curated import of common tactics)

Similarly, `import tactic` also works (which I think is the same as `import tactic.basic` but I could be mistaken).

As for whether it is in mathlib, the answer is yes, and can be found by selecting "Related declarations" to see the definition of `obtain`, [`tactic.interactive.obtain`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactic/rcases.html#tactic.interactive.obtain). If you click on the source you see it is in mathlib.  This means you need mathlib to use it, but most Lean 3 projects require mathlib and it is [easy to add to your project](https://leanprover-community.github.io/leanproject.html).

Here is an [example](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20tactic%0A%0Aexample%20%28p%20q%20%3A%20Prop%29%20%28h%20%3A%20true%20-%3E%20p%20%E2%88%A7%20q%29%20%3A%20p%20%3A%3D%0Abegin%0Aobtain%20%E2%9F%A8hp%2C%20hq%E2%9F%A9%20%20%3A%20p%20%E2%88%A7%20q%2C%0Aapply%20h%2C%0Atrivial%2C%0Aassumption%0Aend).

```
import tactic

example (p q : Prop) (h : true -> p ∧ q) : p :=
begin
  obtain ⟨hp, hq⟩  : p ∧ q,
    apply h,
    trivial,
  assumption
end
```